# Touch event simulation using uinput in a linux based hmi screen is not working?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, uinput

Below is the code using which i am trying to send the touch event to our hmi from user space . All the ioctl calls and write are checked explicitly to be successful but the event is not injected. The vendor id and product id device name is not properly entered . Not sure if it is relevant for the output. (All the three methods of event injection has already been tried out one by one). It vendor id product id and device name is required , then from where in a Linux based Embedded system will we get those data.

```
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/uinput.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

void injectEvent(int, int, int, int);

int main()
{
    struct uinput_user_dev dev;
    int i;
    int err;
    int fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(fd < 0) {
        //perror("Failed to open: /dev/uinput");
        printf("Failed to open: /dev/uinput\n");
        return fd;
    }

    err = ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
    if (err)
        goto err;

    err = ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_ABS);
    if (err)
        goto err;

    err = ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TOUCH);
    if (err)
        goto err;

    err = ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_MT_SLOT);
    if (err)
        goto err;

    memset(&dev, 0, sizeof(dev));
    snprintf(dev.name, sizeof(dev.name), "Test device");
    printf("devname = %s\n",dev.name);
    dev.id.bustype = BUS_SPI;

    /* 10 touch inputs */
    dev.absmax[ABS_MT_SLOT] = 10;

    dev.absmax[ABS_X] = 4096;
    dev.absmin[ABS_X] = 0;

    dev.absmax[ABS_Y] = 4096;
    dev.absmin[ABS_Y] = 0;

    dev.absmax[ABS_PRESSURE] = 0xff;
    dev.absmin[ABS_PRESSURE] = 0;

    dev.absmax[ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR] = 0xff;
    dev.absmin[ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR] = 0;

    dev.absmax[ABS_MT_POSITION_X] = 4096;
    dev.absmin[ABS_MT_POSITION_X] = 0;

    dev.absmax[ABS_MT_POSITION_Y] = 4096;
    dev.absmin[ABS_MT_POSITION_Y] = 0;

    dev.absmax[ABS_MT_PRESSURE] = 4096;
    dev.absmin[ABS_MT_PRESSURE] = 0;

    err = write(fd, &dev, sizeof(dev));
    if (err < 0)
        goto err;

    err = ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE);
    if (err < 0)
        goto err;

    /* Event should be injected here.... */

    /********************First Method***********************/
#if 1
    struct input_event ev[2];

    memset(ev, 0, sizeof(ev));

    ev[0].type = EV_ABS;
    ev[0].code = ABS_X;
    ev[0].value = 1001;
    ev[1].type = EV_ABS;
    ev[1].code = ABS_Y;
    ev[1].value = 2002;

    if(write(fd, &ev, sizeof(ev)) < 0)
        printf("Error::event injection failed\n");

#endif

    /********************Second Method***********************/
#if 0
    injectEvent( fd, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID, 0  );
    injectEvent( fd, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_POSITION_X, 1001  );
    injectEvent( fd, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y, 2002  );
    injectEvent( fd, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR,    111 );
    injectEvent( fd, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_PRESSURE,   3003 );
    injectEvent( fd, EV_SYN, SYN_MT_REPORT, 0   );
    injectEvent( fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0  );
    injectEvent( fd, EV_SYN, SYN_MT_REPORT, 0   );
    injectEvent( fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0  );

    void injectEvent(int fd_ev,int type, int code, int value)
    {
        printf("(%s)==>> (%d,%d,%d,%d)\n",__func__, fd_ev, type, code, value);

        struct uinput_event event;
        int len;

        if (fd_ev <= fileno(stderr))
            return;

        memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
        event.type = type;
        event.code = code;
        event.value = value;

        len = write( fd_ev, &event, sizeof(event) );

        printf("(%s) done:%d\n",__func__,len);
    }
#endif

    /********************Third Method***********************/
#if 0
    struct uinput_event event;
    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));

        event.type=EV_ABS;
        event.code=ABS_X;
        event.value=1005;

        if(write(fd, &event, sizeof(event)) < 0)
            printf("Error::event injection failed\n");

        sleep (5);
    }
#endif

    sleep (180);
    /* start cleanup ... */
    err = ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_DESTROY);
    if (err < 0)
        goto err;

    close(fd);
    return 0;
err:
    //perror("Failed to initialise");
    printf("(%s) Failed to initialise\n",__func__);
    close(fd);
    return err;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your solution, but ABS_X and ABS_Y cannot be set together with ABS_MT_POSITION_X and *_Y, they cannot live together, you have to activate one or another. You can check this using "xinput list-props + device number" in linux. Hope it helped you ;)